# There is a unique line passing through any two points?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This is from *Kiselev's Geometry: Planimetry*, page 2:

> For every two points in space there is a straight line passing through them, and such a line is unique.

So I have two fixed points, and I draw a line through them. Now I make an exact copy of the line, and the copy coincides with the original. It seems like I should be allowed to say: "I have two lines passing through the same points". But the book says that a line passing through two fixed points is unique, so there seems to be a contradiction here.

If I move the copy and the original so they no longer coincide, are they still just one line, or are they two lines now?

Comment: If move the line such that they no longer coincide, then the line would not pass through the two points.

Comment: Two lines which coincide are considered the same line.  If you've given the first line the label $l_1$ and the second the label $l_2$, then you've essentially just labelled the same object in two different ways (which is fine but it doesn't make them distinct objects).

Comment: @DHMO Right. So when two lines pass through the same points they are considered to be one line, but if they are moved apart they are considered to be two lines?

Comment: @Ovi the theorem is that if you have two lines which pass through the same pair of points, then they must coincide.

Comment: @Ovi The statement implies a line is determined by two points through which it passes.  If you move the line, it doesn't pass through the same two points and hence it isn't the same line.

Comment: @Dylan ,DHMO Okay thanks it makes sense.

Comment: I think it's unclear what "make a copy" means. What is a "copy" of a line? This has not been defined.

Comment: Maybe Ovi thinks that a point is an object that *has* a location in the plane, and can be picked up and put down at a different location, with all its other properties the same.  But in Euclidean geometry is point *is* a location in the plane and nothing more, so it does not make sense to say you are moving it somewhere else.

Comment: @MJD Ah yes that's precisely what I thought. It does make more sense now if I think of points as holes in a paper, rather than small molecules, which is how I thought of them before. So I guess I am also wrong about thinking of a line as a thing that you can pick up and move around, it's just a set of locations (holes in the paper). Is there any resource I can read about these "philosophical" issues? I think I may have more of these misconceptions that are hard for me to pinpoint like you just did.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your first line, say $g$, and your copy $g'$, then you can say that you have two lines ($g$ and $g'$) passing through the same points. But these two lines are coincide as you mentioned yourself so you do not have two **distinct** lines through the same points. What they mean by *unique* is that there is no line that does not coincide exactly with the first one **and** passes through the same two points.

And if you move your second line it is considered a transformation and it is now a new line distinct from the original line. That is what is meant by unique. Two lines going through the same two points are actually equal, therefore the same line. All you actually did was assign a new label or different variable, but the new variable can be shown to be equal to the original variable, therefore they are the same. There weren't two lines, to begin with, just different names for the same thing.