# Are points in an Euclidean plane stationary?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Below I have illustrated my two possible interpretations of a line segment being translated:

**Interpretation 1:**

[image]

**Interpretation 2:**

[image]

In the first interpretation, the plane is completely empty, but we are allowed to "speak into existence" a line segment, which we can then push around. The segment in the final position is made up of the same original points

In the second interpretation, every point is already in existence. We define the line segment to be a certain set of points. When we translate said segment, we don't (can't) move the original points. We merely color in different points at the desired final location.

Which of these interpretations, if any, is correct?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?  It seems that in either case, you are describing an intuitive idea rather than something mathematically precise.

Comment: @EricWofsey This question was sparked by MJD's comment on one of my other questions: "Maybe Ovi thinks that a point is an object that has a location in the plane, and can be picked up and put down at a different location, with all its other properties the same. But in Euclidean geometry is point is a location in the plane and nothing more, so it does not make sense to say you are moving it somewhere else." https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231043/there-is-a-unique-line-passing-through-any-two-points

Comment: Note that isometries are often call rigid motion transformations. From an analytical point of view, the equations are the same and either interpretation is valid.